# One from Landau's Minimum (Macroscopic Electrodynamics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-electrodynamics

A dielectric
sphere with the electric and magnetic susceptibilities ε1 and µ1 is rotating with
angular frequency ω in a constant electric field E~ in a medium, characterized
by the parameters ε2 and µ2. The angle between the rotation axis and the
direction of E~ is α. Find the electric and magnetic fields inside the sphere and
in the medium.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! Please have a look at [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583).